# Where is my PHP if elseif breaking?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use this little bit of PHP to randomize my header+background (while still matching each other) on a Wordpress site. Here's what I've come up with so far, but some how it's not displaying right. Here's my code to start:

```
<?php
    $bg = array(
                'dinorun.css',
                'potato.css',
                'glorkian.css',
                'somethingelse.css',
                'anothersomething.css'
              );
    $randombg = mt_rand(0,4);
 if (in_category('dino run')) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/dinorun.css">
<?php } elseif (in_category('potatoman')) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/potatoman.css">
<?php } elseif (in_category(array('glorkian','glork'))) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/glorkian.css">
<?php } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . $bg[$randombg]; ?>" >
<?php } ?>
```

(Edit: formatted code to make it slightly more readable, also made some fixes though it still doesn't work right)

Now what happens is when I go to a specific page in the category 'dino run' (or one of the others) this will display all properly, but somehow on a page that is not categorized for example the Home page, it will actually only display the potatoman css. I actually haven't implimented these css changes yet I've just been testing my php function so far and checking my head to see if my code exists.

Comment: `bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/' . $bg[$randombg];` perhaps: If you do a "view source" of an uncategorised page, what do you see in the stylesheet link?

Comment: Formatting your code helps.

Comment: What's the output of your link tag? Probably Mark's comment is right; you could tell by reading the HTML

Comment: ur missing the closing tag for the last <link

Comment: And why `mt_rand(0, 3);` when you have (not 4 but) 5 CSS files in your array.

Comment: I just threw in a couple extras for more random testing, I should have done 0,4..
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/pjwp/wp-content/themes/pjam2014/potatoman.css">` Is what is showing up. (I added recently the type just because).
@FreshPrinceOfSO what do you mean formatting your code?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/' .  $bg[$randombg]; ?>" />
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . $bg[$randombg]; ?>"
```

So two things:

- You are missing a `/` between your directory and the file.
- You never close the `link` tag which will probably cause problems as well.

Just as a side note.
I think it should be `mt_rand(0, 4);` because you have (not 4 but) 5 CSS files in your array.

Comment: I fixed that, but unfortunately the main page still somehow just displays the potatoman one no matter how many times I refresh. I don't quite understand why it's still displaying that one. I thought perhaps caching, but no caching is taking place AFAIK.

Comment: What does your `in_category('dino run')` do?

Comment: It will display this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/pjwp/wp-content/themes/pjam2014/dinorun.css">`
So it works when I go to the real category. Same for the "Glorkian" category page, it will display `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/pjwp/wp-content/themes/pjam2014/glorkian.css">`

Comment: Yes, but what does your function `in_category` return?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to echo that out so it shows what its returning for a page.

Comment: I suppose you could do `print(in_category('dino run'))`.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with my `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>` code... I tried to throw in either an echo or that print you suggested and nothing gets outputted. Actually I tried throwing in an echo for some generic text after that potatoman.css link and it didn't show up either. I'm so confused. =|

There's also a random `<style type="text/css"></style>` that is showing up which is not in my header.php at all just before the <link> for the potatoman.css

Comment: Turn on your errors and see what you get. Im guessing there is something wrong.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors. Using WAMP display_errors and error_reporting are both on and I used an example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to make sure errors were reporting. I got some errors elsewhere on the page, but not in the head.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing slash after stylesheetdirectory and before randombg in hfef

Answer (score 0):

i guess your bloginfo function echos style sheet path then you should do this

bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); echo $bg[$randombg];

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is much different from what I'm already doing except for skipping the `.` 
Anyways, I have tried both ways and it has no effect.

Comment: . operator concats two strings, if in_category actually echos the path  then i don't think you can concat echoed value with another string as that echoed value is not string. if your function returns actual string instead of echoing the value, then you can use . to concat two strings in that case you should echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . $bg[$randombg];

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately this is not the problem I'm having. I did an `echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` and it does output the path, so I fixed this, but unfortunately my code still does not work.